# i created 500k Array size and i want fill it with random numbers without duplicate

Tags: java

i need to fill this array with 500000 int numbers this my code

```
public class lab_02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // 500000 Array
        Array array = new Array (500000);
   }

  }
```

i don't know what should i do use loop or Recursion 
 thank you

Comment: `Array` seems to be a custom class (from you, your teacher) but not a standard class. You should tell us what methods exist to add elements to it.

Comment: What are the bounds on your desired random numbers? E.g. min 1 max 500000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part here is ensuring uniqueness. Checking if an item is unique can be expensive. Since the OP does not state what the bounds on the random numbers are I am assuming min 1 and max 500000 for this solution.

One approach would be to enter the numbers sequentially 0 to 500000 and then shuffle the array.

```
int size = 500000;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: I don't read "sequential numbers from 1 to 500000" anywhere. I read "random numbers".

Comment: If you iterate over the list of numbers at the end they will be in random order.

Comment: The OP didn't state what the bounds on the random numbers are. The solution I propose will work if the bounds are min 1 and max 500000.

Comment: Yes, "random order", but not "random numbers".

Comment: Right but if the bounds are min 1 and max 500000 and they must all be unique then you must have all the numbers from 1 to 500000.

Comment: Did anyone state that the numbers should be between 1 and 500000 ? No: only that they have to be `int`.

Comment: Nope that is why I said I was making an assumption.

Comment: You edited your answer after all my comments... -_- Please don't say you said it before, the edit history can be seen by anyone.

Comment: I was referring to the 3rd comment in which I acknowledged that the OP did not state the bounds.

Answer (score 4):

1) If you don't need duplicates use a Set

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

2) Then you can add your random generated int add it to the Set

```
while (intSet.size() < DESIRED_SIZE) {
//generate the randomInteger - DESIRED_SIZE is 500k in your case 
intSet.add(randomInteger);
}
```

Comment: Please finish the answer: it's a very good start. To finish, add the `while (intSet.size() < 500_000) { ... }`.

Comment: Well I thought the question was about creating the "Array" not how to populate it :P

Comment: The question explicitly says "need to **fill**" ;)

Comment: One issue here is if the bounds on the random numbers are 1 to 500000, you are going to have to generate a lot more than 500000 random numbers as you fill your set because of the duplicates. Did you try this, how long did it take. How long does it take with bounds on the random numbers.